# Is there a Python equivalent of vfork in Unix?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7, unix

I'm reading APUE.

```
#include "apue.h"
int     globvar = 6;        /* external variable in initialized data */
int main(void)
{
    int     var;        /* automatic variable on the stack */
    pid_t   pid;
    var = 88;
    printf("before vfork\n");   /* we don′t flush stdio */
    if ((pid = vfork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("vfork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) {      /* child */
        globvar++;              /* modify parent′s variables */
        var++;
        _exit(0);               /* child terminates */
    }
   /* parent continues here */
   printf("pid = %ld, glob = %d, var = %d\n", (long)getpid(), globvar, var);
   exit()

}
```

It's said that vfork() creates a child process without copying the address space the parent process has. And parent will wait until child process calls exit or exec. 
Is there anything similar in Python give this kind of low level control? How can this be achieved in Python if possible?

Comment: On Linux a fork in Python is usually copy on write.

Comment: This use of `vfork` is already undefined behavior in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vfork` is a mostly-obsolete optimization of `fork`, intended solely for uses where it is immediately followed by an `exec`. It was designed back when `fork` didn't use copy-on-write, and has been rendered almost entirely pointless by copy-on-write.

Your use of `vfork` is undefined behavior; modifying variables like `globvar` or `var` in the child is not allowed. Almost the only thing the child is allowed to do is call one of the `exec*` functions. The details are in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html).

If your goal is to share memory between Python processes, you should do that with the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`multiprocessing.sharedctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes).

If your goal is to call `vfork`, go ahead and call it with `ctypes`, and watch your program immediately fall apart because it's impossible to call `vfork` safely from Python:

```
$ cat asdf.py
import ctypes
import os

lib = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
vfork = lib.vfork

if not vfork():
    os.execv('/usr/bin/echo', ['echo', 'hello', 'world'])

print("Should print in parent, but doesn't due to memory corruption.")
$ python3.6 asdf.py
hello world
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your use of vfork is undefined behavior; modifying variables like globvar or var in the child is not allowed. >>> But the program is extracted from the book APUE?

Comment: @alan23273850: It's from the book, but it's still undefined behavior. Even the book agrees. Quoting the book, "This optimization is more efficient on some implementations of the UNIX System, but leads to undefined results if the child modifies any data (except the variable used to hold the return value from vfork)..."

Comment: ok i see, thank you very much!